# hosting website my own PC "Ubuntu Server" DMZ

Tags: networking, dns

i got curious about turning my local ubuntu server for my personal website
i set DMZ to see my ubuntu server
and in domain registrar i set my IP and NS i set with bind9...
however i can only see my website via IP address not with the domain name

ps: i have only 1 static ip and its set in my router
so my question is is there anyway to actually host my local machine to see my website with name like http://example.com from internet or not

if there is a way i appreciate the guide or point to article etc...
tnX for help in advance

Comment: To clarify: 1) are you able to see your website **from Internet outside** by IP address, or only from your local network? 2) what exactly did you set up in DNS? Did you assign your external IP address to your domain name? 3) how long ago did you do it? DNS changes may need up to 48 hours to propagate...

Comment: 1) yes i can see ubuntu apache2 default page not my router page
2). if you mean in domain registrar website i set both NS i made by BIND9 and my router IP
3). 48h passed from same local network my other pcs can see the domain with name
but from other networks like my mobile or my friends can't see it unless enter the IP address not the actual domain name

Comment: Could you share exactly a) what data did you enter on your domain registrar website; b) how is your BIND configured (the part of /etc/named.conf where your domain is defined and the actual zone file for your domain)? It's hard to spot any error without having the actual data...

Answer (score 0):

well after lots of error and trial i founded there is no need to set local dns binding
just had to bind my router PUBLIC IP as A record in bind9 settings! not my local ip settings

now im hosting my own website on my pc well till next router reset and getting new public IP

well since there were no help on this i hope someone find this useful
Cheers